# Connecting APC SmartUps 1400

Tags: usb

I have recently gotten my hand on a 2nd hand APC SmartUPS 1400 that I'm trying to connect to my Ubuntu server.

My config is as follows:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- APCUPSD 3.14.12
- HP MicroServer Gen8

The server doesn't come equipped with a serial port. I have therefore borrowed a usb->serial adapter that shows up as `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Prolific_Technology_Inc._USB-Serial_Controller-if00-port0` (and `/dev/ttyUSB0`) when it is plugged in.

In apcupsd.conf I have tried several different settings for UPSCABLE, UPSTYPE and DEVICE, but no matter the combination, I can't get the apcupsd daemon to start.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/apcupsd), with no success so far.

When i run `apcaccess status` I just get the error:

`Error contacting apcupsd @ 127.0.0.1:3551: Connection refused`

which I suppose makes sense since the daemon isn't running.

Can anybody give me hint as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I believe that the port on the UPS is not a standard serial port. Check here for cable part numbers and wiring to make your own cable http://pinoutguide.com/UPS/apc_smart_cable_pinout.shtml. And here http://www.apcupsd.org/manual/manual.html#supported-upses-and-cables for options on configuring apcupsd.conf.

Comment: @heynnema The link to pinoutguide.com helped. Using the simple scheme and a jumper box, I can now run apcaccess status without any problems. When I have the necessary parts, I will make myself a cable without the jumper box. If you write an answer, I will accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: Glad you got it going! Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

I believe that the port on the UPS is not a standard serial port. Check here for cable part numbers and wiring to make your own cable...

http://pinoutguide.com/UPS/apc_smart_cable_pinout.shtml

And here...

http://apcupsd.org/manual/manual.html#supported-upses-and-cables

for options on configuring apcupsd.conf.